# Not have to create new element each time?

Tags: html, css

I want to be able to have only one id for this and create new elements for the img part only. I've tried using an img tag the img goes to the foreground and the feathered edges doesn't work. Images only same for debug

[Jfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bLbjw7rh/)

```css
#webdevimage1 {
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 6px 6px #f5f5f5 inset;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 6px 6px #f5f5f5 inset;
  box-shadow: 0 0 6px 6px #f5f5f5 inset;
  background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/fxKJClv.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  width: 320px;
  height: 200px;
  background-size: 320px 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#webdevimage2 {
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 6px 6px #f5f5f5 inset;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 6px 6px #f5f5f5 inset;
  box-shadow: 0 0 6px 6px #f5f5f5 inset;
  background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/fxKJClv.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  width: 320px;
  height: 200px;
  background-size: 320px 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#webdevimage3 {
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 6px 6px #f5f5f5 inset;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 6px 6px #f5f5f5 inset;
  box-shadow: 0 0 6px 6px #f5f5f5 inset;
  background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/fxKJClv.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  width: 320px;
  height: 200px;
  background-size: 320px 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#webdevimage4 {
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 6px 6px #f5f5f5 inset;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 6px 6px #f5f5f5 inset;
  box-shadow: 0 0 6px 6px #f5f5f5 inset;
  background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/fxKJClv.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  width: 320px;
  height: 200px;
  background-size: 320px 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="webdevtable">
  <table width="660px" height="300px" cellpadding="2px" cellspacing="3px">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div id="webdevimage1"></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div id="webdevimage2"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div id="webdevimage3"></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div id="webdevimage4"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: what exactly you want to do ?

Comment: Have #webdevimage defining all the properties and then new ids with only the background image or be able to define all the properties and only the background image in html, so I don't need to repeat 10 lines of code every time I add a new image

Comment: create one common class and apply it in all the div. https://jsfiddle.net/bLbjw7rh/6/

Comment: Try this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/bLbjw7rh/3/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use css class for this instead of defining the style for each element.

See the updated fiddle here : https://jsfiddle.net/bLbjw7rh/4/

```
<div id="webdevtable">
    <table width="660px" height="300px" cellpadding="2px" cellspacing="3px">
        <tr>
            <td><div id="webdevimage1" class="webdevimage"></div></td> <td><div id="webdevimage2" class="webdevimage"></div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><div id="webdevimage3" class="webdevimage"></div></td> <td><div id="webdevimage4" class="webdevimage"></div></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Here i have assigned a common class with all the common styling. Based on the ID, different image can be assigned as well.